# Create a GXT Grid with dynamic columns

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a requirement where columns change dynamically in grid based on the type of file that is being opened.

There are some custom file extensions, these files have some data which have to be shown in grid. The number of columns for different file formats is different. But for a particular extension the number of columns are fixed.

How do I create a grid dynamically in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a grid with some default columns which would later change depending on the type of the file.
2. Once you have the file type, create a new columnModel and call `grid.reconfigure(store,newColumnModel)`